# Trigger is not working for field update?

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger Contact_Role_Update on Opportunity(after update) {

    list<OpportunityContactRole> listContact = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();

    listContact = [SELECT OpportunityId, Contact.AccountId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId IN: trigger.newMap.keyset()];
    System.debug('listContact is --->:'+listContact);
    if (listContact.size() > 0) {
        for (OpportunityContactRole con: listContact) {
            if(con.Contact.AccountId ==Null){
               con.Contact.AccountId = trigger.newMap.get(con.OpportunityId).AccountId;
               System.debug('Account Id to be assigned --->:'+trigger.newMap.get(con.OpportunityId).AccountId);
            }
        }
        update listContact;
        System.debug('updated contact role');
    }
}
```

I am trying to update AccountId of contact role. Trigger is executing fetching the correct accountid but contact field is not updating.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Are you sure that this line is correct? `con.Contact.AccountId ==Null `

Comment: Yes  trigger is executing no error only field is not updating and if I remove this line con.Contact.AccountId ==Null even after that not updating the field

Comment: I think in `if` condition it should be something like this `con.ContactId.AccountId == null`

Comment: Yeah, maybe you should try with `ContactId`, that is the right field on the OpportunityContactRole object.

Comment: Even if I remove the If condition still not updating the field and if I put as con.ContactId.AccountId == null as suggested then will get error as :Invalid foreign key relationship: OpportunityContactRole.ContactId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do an update on OpportunityContactRole, it only updates fields on the object itself. It does not update objects linked via a reference field.

So, when you update an OpportunityContactRole, con, you can update con.ContactId, but you cannot update con.Contact.AccountId because AccountId is not directly on the OpportunityContactRole object.

You would need to be calling update on actual Contacts like this:

```
trigger Contact_Role_Update on Opportunity(after update) {

    list<OpportunityContactRole> listContact = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();

    listContact = [SELECT OpportunityId, ContactId, Contact.AccountId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId IN: trigger.newMap.keyset()];
    Map<Id, Contact> contactsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Contact>();
    System.debug('listContact is --->:'+listContact);
    if (listContact.size() > 0) {
        for (OpportunityContactRole con: listContact) {
            if(con.Contact.AccountId ==Null){
               Contact thisContactToUpdate = new Contact(Id = con.ContactId, AccountId = trigger.newMap.get(con.OpportunityId).AccountId);

               contactsToUpdate.put(thisContactToUpdate.Id, thisContactToUpdate);
               System.debug('Account Id to be assigned --->:'+trigger.newMap.get(con.OpportunityId).AccountId);
            }
        }
        update contactsToUpdate.values();
        System.debug('updated contact role');
    }
}
```

Note, I haven't run that code in SF to test it, but it should be close enough to allow you to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your current code to work then you will have to make your trigger work in **Before Update** context rather than **After update**. If you see your code properly nowhere you have provided the **ID** which you want to update in the after context. If you update in **Before** context then it will not require the id.

If you want to update in the **After** context then you will have to modify your trigger in the below way.

```
trigger Contact_Role_Update on Opportunity(after update) 
{

    list<OpportunityContactRole> listContact = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();
    list<OpportunityContactRole> ContacttoUpdate = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();

    listContact = [SELECT OpportunityId, Contact.AccountId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId IN: trigger.newMap.keyset()];
    System.debug('listContact is --->:'+listContact);

    if (listContact.size() > 0) 
    {
        for (OpportunityContactRole con: listContact) 
        {
            if(con.Contact.AccountId == Null)
            {
                OpportunityContactRole OCR = New OpportunityContactRole;

                OCR.Id = Con.Id;
                OCR.Contact.AccountId = trigger.newMap.get(con.OpportunityId).AccountId;
               ContacttoUpdate.add(OCR);               
            }
        }
        System.debug('Id's to be updated --->:'+ContacttoUpdate);
        update ContacttoUpdate;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you have provided your **IF** condition correctly. Check for that also once by putting a debug statement.

Also I would suggest you to adhere to the salesforce best practice by writing the code logic in a separate class and calling that class in the trigger. This will help you in future to maintain code properly.

Hope this helps!!

Regards!
Ruchi

Comment: will get null pointer exception at this line:  OCR.Contact.AccountId = trigger.newMap.get(con.OpportunityId).AccountId;

Comment: @avidForce: Ohh maybe . I have not tested the code. I was just trying to tell that in after trigger we need to create a separate list of object id's to be updated and the update them.